# How to let a plane follow a lattice

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to learn how to use a lattice and on the image can you see what I have so far. I made the roof and the beams follow the lattice but now I also want the side walls (marked with a red color) to follow the same lattice so that I get an easy to edit shape.

- I tried to create a plane and link it to the lattice but that did not work.
- I tried to seperate the top vertices of the plane and let them follow the lattice. did not work.

Download the blend file [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5E81B0C540A634B5!31692&authkey=!ANigBgmNLPd8Vqo&ithint=file%2Cblend)

Is there anybody here who has an idea how I can fix this?

thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Generally every object which should be modified using lattice should have enough geometry to be bent. Also make sure it has transforms applied (`Ctrl`+`A`). From your screenshot isn't clear - would you like the walls to be the same form as the roof is ? It's not ususal for walls to be like that. Is it possible for you to add more screenshots and / or [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: @MrZak I added the blend file to the question. what I want is a plane that fills up the space below the beams (in this case a shape like the red area). In the blend file can you see what happens when I add the lattice to the plane.

Comment: I see now. This won't work with lattice set up like that because it will just bent wall (what it does) in the same manner as the roof. You could get this effect if there would be cube in a form of desired wall or lattice [like this](http://imgur.com/PJum0pU). Cube could be used as a domain with Boolean added to cut everything above and below. Lattice could be used as usual but I don't think it's possible right now without applying modifiers to cut that wall appropriately in real-time.

Comment: @MrZak okay, I understand. thanks for your time looking at the problem